# iOS YouTube authentication EXC_BAD_EXCEPTION

Tags: ios, youtube

I ran this code [here](https://github.com/NSRover/YouTube-API-Demo), and it worked perfectly.
However, I’m facing a problem when trying to add it to my project.
After the class **YouTubeHelper** call `showAuthenticationViewController:`

```
– (void)showAuthenticationViewController:(UIViewController *)authView {
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:authView animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Inside GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.m I’m getting an `exc_bad_access`, inside `loadView`, on `[super loadView]`, as below:

```
– (void)loadView {
    NSString *nibPath = nil;
    NSBundle *nibBundle = [self nibBundle];
    if (nibBundle == nil) {
        nibBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    }
    NSString *nibName = self.nibName;
    if (nibName != nil) {
        nibPath = [nibBundle pathForResource:nibName ofType:@”nib”];
    }
    if (nibPath != nil && [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:nibPath]) {
        [super loadView]; <<<< exc_bad_access here!
    } else {
        // One of the requirements of loadView is that a valid view object is set to
        // self.view upon completion. Otherwise, subclasses that attempt to
        // access self.view after calling [super loadView] will enter an infinite
        // loop due to the fact that UIViewController's -view accessor calls
        // loadView when self.view is nil.
        self.view = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];

#if DEBUG
        NSLog(@"missing %@.nib", nibName);
#endif
    }
}
```

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: This demo has the last update over a year ago, so I think that Google's API is changed and that could break this demo. So you better make some research and refer to official docs, rather than trying to understand a code which is not maintained and could be covered with lots of bugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Midhun and EridB.

As the libraries are a little bit old, I did my own implementation to upload videos to YouTube.

Here some links that helped on it:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/videos

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/using_resumable_upload_protocol

Specially this one was very useful to try and check request/response:

https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/?code=4/1c_ILMzPMhgPWpCI6L7M-LeBe5jL-BY1Xa1sS0oWQJ0

I hope it helps others with YouTube API implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You should never call `[super loadView];` in your subclass. Remove that line from your implementation.

> You can override this method in order to create your views manually. If you choose to do so, assign the root view of your view
>   hierarchy to the view property. The views you create should be unique
>   instances and should not be shared with any other view controller
>   object. Your custom implementation of this method should not call
>   super.

Reference: [UIViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/loadView)

Comment: That is not my class. It's from Google API GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.m

Comment: @FabioBergmann: Hmm, that's interesting. Well, I've added Apple's API reference for you to check.

Comment: I ran the code on that link, using same Google API, same class, and it works without problem. Only when I do the same to my project I get that bad access.

Comment: The only thing I want with Google API is to upload video to YouTube. Is there any other simple library or even a pod to do that? I didn't find anything else.

Comment: @FabioBergmann: I didn't used any such libraries previously, but hope this one can help you : https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-iOS